# Is there a C++ STL function to compare a value against a compile-time constant?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I've implemented the following function in a utility library:

```
template <auto Value>
bool equals_constant(const decltype(Value)& value) { return Value == value; }
```

It's useful with other template functions which take an invocable predicate, like this:

```
template <auto IsValid>
struct Validator {
    bool validate(int value) { return IsValid(value); }
};

// this validator requires its value to equal 42 (just for demo purposes)
Validator<equals_constant<42>> validator;
std::cout << validator.validate(41) << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << validator.validate(42) << std::endl; // 1
```

**Have I reinvented the wheel** - is something like my `equals_constant()` already in the STL? (If so, I can't find it on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) or Google.) Thanks.

Comment: You can not assert that `operator==` is noexcept on a template type.

Comment: @Caduchon I can when I know what types I'm instantiating it with... this is in no way relevant to the question, but I'll remove the `noexcept` specifier from the example to avoid further confusion. (By the way, my "real" function also has a `std::enable_if` to check that the `Value` type is `std::is_trivial`, but I omitted this since, again, it's in no way whatsoever relevant to the question.)

Comment: @TypeIA it's relevant because you can not find something with this specification in the STL. If `noexcept` is not required, don't put it in the signature of the function. If it's required, you have to limit your types (with a static_assert, for example).

Comment: @Caduchon Understood - please forget about the `noexcept`. I have removed it from the example. Thanks.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but condionally noexcpet functions are a thing.

Comment: You are right. I expected that there is already a predefined predicate for comparing with a non const var. But that is not the case. So simply forget about my last comment!

Comment: Not sure something like that will ever make it into the standard library intentionally. Especially given C++20's changes to lambdas. We can provide the predicate inline https://godbolt.org/z/eKzYsGsjd - Granted, the dedicated utility has the advantage of readability and declarative style, but that's not helpful on its own for standardization.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica your insight seems like a good answer for C++20. Would you like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `std` *isn't* a place where "anything vaguely useful" gets put.

[`boost::hana::equal.to`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_comparable.html#gacaf1ebea6b3ab96ac9dcb82f0e64e547) looks to be similar.

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but I'm not sure I agree in general that "vaguely useful things" don't get into the STL. Just look at all the stuff in `<algorithm>` and `<functional>`.

Comment: @TypeIA the criteria isn't "vaguely useful to someone", it's "either widely useful, or vaguely useful to library writers for implementing the widely useful parts", where the extra stuff gets specified in based on the demonstrating implementation.